# How does Horner method evaluate the derivative of a function

Tags: derivatives, numerical-methods

From my understanding, Horner method is mainly used to evaluate polynomial functions by altering the equation into a simpler recursive relation with lesser number of operations.
Say for example, I was given $f (x) = 4x^4 + 3x^3 +2x^2+x+5$
This can be rewritten as $5 +x (1+x (2+x (3+x (4)))$

Were we can evaluate the function as a recurrent relation of simpler terms starting from:

$b_n=4 $

$b_{n-1} = 3 + b_n* x$

And $b_0$ would be the whole term evaluated and therefore the image of the function. 
What I want to understand how is running horner method to the $b_n$ values result in the derivative?

Comment: @JeanMarie: Links are overlapped therefore clicking doesn't lead to any of them.

Comment: Here is the first link, the most interesting :(cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Calculus/HornerMethod.shtml)

Answer (score 5):

If you apply the Horner scheme, or perhaps the Ruffini method (both originally published papers on variants of the Newton method that use a trick for fast polynomial evaluation that was previously well-known), then you perform a polynomial division with remainder by a linear term. From the Horner table, you can read off the coefficients for a polynomial $q$ so that
$$
p(x)=p(a)+(x-a)q(x)\iff q(x)=\frac{p(x)-p(a)}{x-a}
$$
which tells you that $q(a)=p'(a)$. A second Horner evaluation below the first table will thus evaluate the derivative value.

---

You can also see this as algorithmic differentiation, if the original algorithm is

```
val = 0
for k=0 to deg
    val = val*x + a[deg-k]
end for
```

then the derivative by using the chain rule in every step gives

```
dval = 0; val = 0
for k=0 to deg
    dval = dval*x + val
    val = val*x + a[deg-k]
end for
```

The derivative steps needs to be computed first as it uses the last value of `val`.

Answer (score 2):

*I do not know if this will answer the question; if it does not, please forgive me.*

Consider the polynomial to be $$p=\sum_{i=1}^n c_i\, x^{i-1}\implies p'=\sum_{i=1}^n (i-1)\, c_i\, x^{i-2}$$ As a pseudo code, you would have

```
  p  = c(n)
  dp = 0
  do j = n-1 , 1 , -1
     dp = dp * x + p
     p  = p  * x + c(j)
  enddo
```

which computes at the same time the polynomial and its derivative with a minimum number of basic operations.

Comment: The first summation (the polynomial $p$, not the derivative $p'$) should have $i=0$. I assume that code is Fortran "pseudocode" - as Fortran isn't all that mainstream, a comment explaining the loop might help. It's not hard to work out that the loop body runs for $j=n-1$ down to $j=0$ inclusive, but that `do` syntax doesn't clearly express that IMO (actually it seems actively misleading, and makes me wonder if the `, 1 ,` should be a `, 0 ,`).

Comment: @Steve314. You are right ! Typo that I shall fix.

Answer (score -1):

The key is to make the indices the same and use original **Horner's rule** in the same for loop to evaluate both polynomial and its derivative.

Let's say the original problem is to compute `f(x)=sum[ c[n] x^n, for {n,0 ,k }]`.

The derivative is of the form `f'(x)=sum[ m c[m] x^(m-1), for {m,1 ,k }]`.
A change of index `n=m-1` make the base of iterator the same, i.e. `f'(x)=sum[ (n+1) c[n+1] x^(n), for {n,0 ,k-1 }]`

Now we have same iterator which can be used except the case `n=k` which only applies to evaluation of function and not the derivative. This case can be computed outside the loop easily.

Here is the way to do it in Python:

```
def horner_eval(x, a):

'''Uses Horner's rule to return the polynomial
   a[n] + a[n+1] x^1 + a[n+2] x^2 + ... + a[0] x^(n)
AND its derivative evaluated at x.
NOTICE: coefficient vector is given backward for ease of indexing
'''

dist, speed = 0, 0

for i in range(len(a) - 1):
    dist = a[i] + (x * dist)
    speed = i * a[i] + (x * speed)

dist = a[-1] + (x * dist) # since function has one term more that the derivative 
return dist, speed
```

`dist` stores the values of the polynomial at `x`.

`speed` stores the values of derivative of the polynomial at `x`.

Comment: You might want to include a little about *why* this evaluates the derivative