# Why is Horner's method for evaluating polynomials not suitable for root finding?

Tags: computational-mathematics

$$ p = \sum_{k = 0}^n a_k x^k $$

Horner's method for evaluating a polynomial:

$$ \begin{align}
p_H &= a_0 + x \left( a_1 + x  \left( a_2 + x  \left( a_3 + .... + x  \left( a_{n -1} + x a_n \right) \right) \right) \right) \\
&... \\
& = a_0 + x \left( a_1 + x b_2 \right) \\
& = a_0 + x b_1 \\
& = b_0
\end{align}$$

So, if $y = (x - 2)^9$ evaluated with $\Delta x = 10^{-4}$, I get this:

[image]

My questions are:

1. Why is less precise than directly computing the value of the polynomial?
2. Why does the error oscillate like that?

I've tried finding the error in each case:

$$ \Delta p = \Delta x \sum_{k = 1}^n k |a_k| |x^{k - 1}| $$

$$ \begin{align}
\Delta p_H &=  \Delta x |b_1| + |x| \Delta b_1 \\
&= \Delta x |b_1| + \Delta x |b_2| + |x| \Delta b_2 \\
&... \\
&= \Delta x(|b_1| + |b_2| + ... + |b_n|) + |a_n| |x| \Delta x \\
&= \Delta x \left( \sum_{k = 1}^n |b_n| + |a_n| |x| \right)
\end{align}$$

So it seems that

$$ \sum_{k = 1}^n |b_n| + |a_n| |x| > \sum_{k = 1}^n k |a_k| |x^{k - 1}| $$

but by how much? What is the intuition behind this?

Comment: It can be suitable for root finding because you can compute values of $f'$ using [an extension of Horner's method](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2139142), and then apply Newton's method.

Comment: @Somos this is what I was looking for, please write your comment as an answer and i'll mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing exactly how you plotted the two functions, it is not possible to know for sure. However, the Horner's method is subject to [loss of significance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance)
due to many floating point additions but the $y=(x−2)^9$ method only does one subtraction. I was able to duplicate essentially the plot you got using Mathematica two ways. For those interested, here is my code:

```
ClearAll[x, y, z, horner]; y = (x - 2)^9; z = y // Expand;
horner[p_, w_, x0_] := With[{a = Reverse@CoefficientList[p, w]}, 
  Fold[x0*#1 + #2 &, Prepend[a, 0]]];
DiscretePlot[{1*^10*horner[z, x, t], 1*^10*y/.x->t}, {t,1.92,2.08,.001}, 
  PlotRange -> {-1.5, 1.5}, AspectRatio -> 1, Filling -> False, 
  PlotLegends -> Placed[{"Horner's", "(x-2)^9"}, Above]]
Plot[{1*^10*horner[z, x, t], 1*^10*(y/.x->t)}, {t, 1.92, 2.08}, 
  PlotRange -> {-1.5, 1.5}, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotPoints -> 3, 
  PlotLegends -> Placed[{"Horner's", "(x-2)^9"}, Above]]
```